# search for '\n in char pointer use c

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to loop a char*str use this to find out how many lines:

```
char *str = "test1\ntest2\ntest3";

int lines = 0;

for(int i = 0 ; i < ?? ; i ++ )
{
    if(str[i] == '\n') {
        lines++;
    }
}
```

I am not sure  what to put at the ??, the question is :

1.I mean do I need to use strlen(str) + 1 ?

2.when the str  is  "test1\ntest2\ntest3\n",does the code still calculate correct lines?

I am using gcc by the way,thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

every literal string ends with `\0` which is a null character..It depicts the end of the string

So,
You can do this

```
for(int i = 0 ; str[i]!='\0' ; i ++ )
```

Comment: Not only literal string constants (why the code formatting there anyway?) but in fact everything C can treat as a “string”.

Answer (score 3):

To extend the already-existent good answers: the idiomatic way for looping through a C string is

```
const char *s = "abc\ndef\nghi\n";
int lines = 0;
int nonempty = 0;
while (*s) {
    nonempty = 1;
    if (*s++ == '\n') lines++;
}
```

If you don't want to count the last empty line as a separate line, then add

```
if (nonempty && s[-1] == '\n' && lines > 0) lines--;
```

after the `while` loop.

Comment: I think the condition at the end should be `if (lines && s[-1] == '\n')`; otherwise unpredictable for the empty string.

Comment: It's still indexing outside of the original string in case it was the empty string.

Comment: @Arkku not anymore (depends on lazy evaluation, before you spot that `str[-1]` is still accessed).

Comment: Any particular reason to introduce the additional variable `nonempty` rather than simply checking for `lines > 0` (which implies `nonempty`) before `s[-1]`? As for `s[-1]` still being accessed, are you referring to some compiler-specific behaviour where optimizations might cause it to be accessed if it is guaranteed to not be a problem?

Comment: @Arkku 1. no specific reason, 2. it's standard behavior.

Comment: Umm, the `&&` and `||` operators are short-circuiting in standard C.

Comment: @Arkku yes, that's what I'm talking about. This behavior of the operators is relied upon in the edit.

Comment: Ah, so the “before you spot that” implied that I would be unaware of this standard behaviour and would mistakenly “spot” this (non-existent) flaw? Fine, although a rather unfounded supposition when my own proposed solution in the first comment already relied on this behaviour to avoid the problem…

Comment: @Arkku Yes, exactly - I'm sorry for that, I see that it is not the case. To be honest, I didn't even notice that you too provided an answer that relies upon this fact.

Answer (score 1):

Take the length of the string and iterate through all characters.

```
const unsigned long length=strlen(str);
for(int i = 0 ; i < length ; i ++ )
{
     if(str[i] == '\n') {
       lines++;
   }
}
```

Comment: loops over the string twice. The `str[i]` resp. `str[i] != '\0'` solution is better.

Answer (score 1):

The following will deliver the same result regardless if the last character is a newline or not.

```
char *abc = "test1\ntest2\ntest3";

int lines = 0;

{
    bool lastWasNewline = true;
    char * p = abc;
    for (; *p; ++p) {
        if (lastWasNewline) ++lines;
        lastWasNewline = *p == '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you compiled this? Declaring two variables of different type in a `for` statement is new to me. And then this test for `strlen` as loop condition is really, really not the the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

in place of `??` put `strlen(abc)` and make sure `#include <string.h>`

For better efficiency do

`int length= strlen(abc);`

and then use `i < length`

Or use `str[i]!= '\0'`

Comment: That's not efficient: at every iteration it will calculate again strlen.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri I doubt OP already cares about efficiency if he can't even enumerate the characters of a string...

Comment: @H2CO3 It's still terrible advice to suggest something like this to beginners when the correct solution is no more complex.

Comment: @Arkku What if I tell you most decent compilers will optimize that out amyway?

Comment: I just informed him to do use this concept .. because in the question itself he mentioned the `strlen` stuff.. So i thought he knows about this so just gave the answer in place of `??`...now i edited..

Comment: @H2CO3 Umm, "the compiler will optimize it" is a considerably worse excuse to teach bad practices than "it doesn't matter in this case"; the compiler's optimization cannot, in the general case, be relied upon, it's not visible in the code, and it causes problems with different compilers & different optimization flags, etc.

Comment: @Arkku Yes, but it's still there and is real.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.I mean do I need to use strlen(str) + 1 ?

no, just use `str[i]` for `i < ??`, this tests if that is the `0` character which terminates the string

> 2.when the abc is "test1\ntest2\ntest3\n",does the code still calculate correct lines?

no, you code assumes that the input is broken into one input line per buffer `line[j]`.

Comment: Don't use `str[i]` for ??, but use `str[i]` instead of `i < ??`.